# Is there any platform where we scan a QR-code and receive the Bitcoin payment?

Tags: paper-wallet, qrcode

Like if I want to send 1 BTC to someone I give him a QR-code. He scans it and receives the money. You load your QR code with Bitcoin as payment voucher.

Comment: can you provide more details on your use case, most mobile wallet applications include QR code functionality

Comment: Sounds like you are thinking of a paper wallet. The private key as a QR code on a piece of paper. Note that there are many dangers to this method.

Comment: Please use proper punctuation in your question. If you want people to take the time to answer your questions, the least you can do is to ask them properly!

Answer (score 1):

A QR Code is just a short-cut for a string of text.

As you probably know, a Bitcoin address is also a string of text. So too, are the keys to your Bitcoin wallet.

So many different things can be stored in a QR code. Is it a wallet address? Or is it a back up of a wallet with its keys? Or is it a web address? Or an email address? It can be anything.

So you can use it to send bitcoin, but you must understand what it is that you are doing and the many ways to do it.

Does the person you want to give the Bitcoin to have a smart phone? Then all you need to do is to install a Bitcoin wallet application and ask the wallet to display its address as a QR code - which you can scan with your own wallet on your own phone which contains the Bitcoin you want to send.

If the person you want to send it to does not have a smart phone, or you can't do the transaction in person, but you have a computer, then you can export or save your wallet as a paper wallet and print it on paper. It depends on the program, but most wallet software have a variation of it and your friend will likely need to use the same software on his computer to import the wallet. Here is a short introduction to this: https://blockchain.info/wallet/paper-tutorial

A third option is to use one of the web based wallet services such as the one above.